# Как в OpenGL или DirectX называется технология затенения углов?

Tags: opengl, графика, directx, шейдеры, технологии

Это запеченные карты света? Или Есть какая то технология позволяющая сделать это программно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Этот эффект затенения на вашей картинке называется [Ambient Occlusion](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_occlusion) или **AO**

Он заключается в затенении поверхностей на основе информации об объектах (поверхностях) рядом.

Реализаций **AO** много, например "пост-эффект" во фрагментном шейдере ([Screen Space Ambient Occlusion](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSAO) или SSAO) на основе информации о положении пикселей и нормалях. Относительно прост и дешев, из за чего и популярен, **не зависит от сложности сцены**.

К недостаткам алгоритма можно отнести **невозможность обработки полу-прозрачных поверхностей + невозможность аппаратного сглаживания** ([antialiasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing)).

---

**SSAO** можно отнести к технике так называемого отложенного рендеринга или [deferred rendering](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (shading)
, это такой фокус, когда вместо кадра на экране формирутся так называемый **G-Buffer** это несколько рендер текстур (render texture) в которые рисуется  кадр, только кроме цвета в каждое значение пикселя записывается информация о:

- xyz пикселя относительно камеры
- векторе нормали к поверхности в этой точке
- любая другая информация (например о типе материала, глубине, и так далее)

В последствии поверх всего экрана рисуется один треугольник, таким образом чтобы он закрыл весь экран. Это нужно чтобы вызвать фрагментный шейдер для каждого
пикселя. В шейдере происходит вся магия. Там  берется информация из сформированного недавно g-buffer и формируется кадр с освещением-затенением.

---

Описанное выше это общая часть для множества алгоритмов освещения, затенения, фильтрации изображений и других странных фокусов вроде [**screen space reflections**](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2018/course/TDA361/Advanced%20Computer%20Graphics/Screen-space%20reflections.pdf), работающих в экранном пространстве. т.е. их сложность растет не со сложностью сцены а с размером кадра.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**SSAO**

Если принять за освещенность точки сумму всех векторов фотонов из полусферы:

[image: hemisphepe]

и предположить что если рядом есть поверхность или объект, то фотоны через него не проходят, тогда получается что их можно не учитывать при расчете освещения.

[image: сэмпирование]

Улучшение результата возможно за счет учета нормалей для обработки плоских поверхностей:

[image: учет нормалей]

Так же дает хорошие результаты не простое [монте-карло](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%BE) по соседним пикселям, а например, [poisson sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_sampling):

[image: poisson samplig]

Вот пример [**screen space AO**](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_sao.html) на **three.js**.