# обработка нормали для шейдера

Tags: opengl, webgl, opengles

Вот например я хочу 3d модель загрузить в шейдеры. Я использую obj формат и в этом формате есть вершины, нормали и текстурные координаты. В шейдере вершины присваиваются `gl_Position`. Но как насчет нормалей. Я долго думал и пришел к выводу, что нормаль должна быть соединена с цветом, но так ли это? Может надо освещение программировать для нормали? Как вообще написать, чтобы нормаль правильно использовать?

Comment: Обычно нормали используют для освещения, но есть и другие варианты. *"Как вообще написать, чтобы нормаль правильно использовать?"* Так вы скажите, какую картинку хотите получить. От этого зависит, что делать с нормалями.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну как для освещения использовать, это зависит от освещения типа блика и т.п.? И какие еще варианты есть? Например я хочу испльзовать нормали для бликового освещения, как тогда код писать надо?

Comment: обычно нормали передаются в виде атрибутов вершин, наряду с любой другой связанной с вершинами информацией, и gl_position это устаревший синтаксис, хоть он и работает. для вершин так же предлагается использовать атрибуты

Comment: @StrangerintheQ и как эту нормаль дальше обрабатывать?

Comment: вот я как-то для конкурса пример делал, тут нормали используются как раз для расчета освещения по фонгу (ищите функцию phongContribForLight во фрагментном шейдере) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924210/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8/927012#927012

Comment: @StrangerintheQ для меня это сложно, видимо не мое это, программировать трехмерную графику. Лучше наверное двухмерную писать, только в двухмерной рисовать красиво надо. А как мне научиться высчитывать bdrf, луч и все такое, уж очень знать хочеться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нормали – это часть геометрии модели, они сами не соединены с цветом, но могут использоваться в вычислениях световых эффектов. Самое базовое применение – затенение. Если нормаль грани противоположна направлению света, то она полностью светла, если перпендикулярная – она полностью затемнена. Другими словами, чем ближе отражённый вектор к нормали, тем светлее:

[image: img_math]

Очень часто применяются карты нормалей (текстуры, чьи цветовые значения используются как числа, изменяющие изначальную нормаль модели) для симуляции неровностей, шероховатости. Сравните 2 кадра одной и той же сцены с и без использования карты нормалей:

[image: img1] [image: img2]

В качестве примера можете посмотреть проект, откуда эти кадры взяты: [OpenGL-Cpp-ObjC-Mac](https://github.com/AivanF/OpenGL-Cpp-ObjC-Mac) – учебное приложение на C++ и OpenGL с обёрткой на Objective-C. Там реализованы различные виды освещения (направленный свет, точечные источники, прожекторы) и тени, а также карты нормалей (накладываемые по вычисляемым касательным), туман, процедурные и загружаемые модели и т.д. – по всем этим темам можно найти более подробную информацию в сети. Особенно интересным окажется файл [full.frag](https://github.com/AivanF/OpenGL-Cpp-ObjC-Mac/blob/master/OpenGL-Cpp-Mac/SceneAssets/Shaders/full.frag) – основной фрагментарный шейдер содержащий бóльшую часть функционала. В коде C++ много классов и абстракций для удобства, но основная логика отрисовки содержится в этом файле: [WorldDrawUsual.cpp](https://github.com/AivanF/OpenGL-Cpp-ObjC-Mac/blob/master/OpenGL-Cpp-Mac/Cpp/WorldDrawUsual.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

В геометрии - нормаль к поверхности это вектор, перпендикулярный ей, однако в компьютерной графике это может быть слегка не так, например для расчета освещения по Фонгу нормали указываются у вершин, и интерполируются между ними.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако интерпретируются они именно как перпендикуляры к поверхностям в интересующей точке, что на выходе дает эффект плавного перехода от освещенных фрагментов к затененным, а не резкий как без этих допущений, используя настоящие нормали.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Так же нормали используются повсеместно в графике для достижения множества всевозможных эффектов. Весь пост процессинг основан на создании `g-buffer` в котором одна из текстур как раз карта нормалей для текущего кадра. Затем эта информация используется для per-pixel расчетов отражений, затенений и много чего другого.

Я не так давно писал пост про [фреймбуферы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/953499/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B/959682#959682) там как раз приведены примеры алгоритмов, все они используют нормали.

Вот более подробный пост про [ambient occlusion](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/954743/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-opengl-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-directx-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2/954746#954746), там как Вы догадались тоже используются нормали.

Comment: Откуда такие познания и невозможность предоставить код шейдеров. Я ведь пишу на си и с++, и мне нужны шейдеры. А у вас только теория.

Comment: давайте. Только простенький пример.

Comment: Да по фонгу пойдет.